# ASP.NET MVC3 Maintain Navigation History

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

*Context*
My System has numerous related entities such as Tenant -> Client -> Campaign -> etc...

Each entity has an "index" view which enables Search, Paging and links to Edit/Details/Delete. In the "detail" view for each entity i have tabs displaying the entity details (read only) plus a additional tabs for any child entity where the user can search, Page and has links to Edit/Details/Delete. This allows the user to navigate "down" the tree (so to speak).

*Problem*
Going down the tree works a treat its coming back up that I cannot figure out.

eg, Goto tentant -> Clients tab. Search for client by name then click on the "details" link for that client. Then goto client -> Campaigns, search for a campaign then click on "edit" for the campaign. make my changes and submit the form. I could have accessed this "edit" view by either the "Campaign/Index" or "Client/Details -> Campaign tab". So how do I maintain this navigation history? The system I am working on can go 6 levels deep and I need something that will work all the way down and back up again. If I can maintain details about the state of each calling page eg. search criteria, page number, active tab etc. that would be ideal but given the complexity of this I would be happy enough just getting back to the correct page and tab.

Worst case scenario is "User" which can be access via 4 different calling pages.

Comment: Can you clarify at what points in your user journey you will be doing page loads vs updating the content of the tabs? E.g. when you click on the details link for the client, does it then do a page load to take you to the client details or is it activating another tab?

Comment: Hi Steve. When clicking on a "tab" the user will be taken to a new page that "looks" the same but with the tab activated. I wrote a custom class for storing the history that I update on every click but this fails when the user uses the browser back button. Misses the event and now the history is out of whack.

Comment: We are facing the same issue at the moment.  Curious to know if you found an approach you were happy with, and if so, what it was?  We're investigating the use of cookie(s) containing navigation history and basic state info.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not store URL's in an (server-side) array and push them in as you traverse down the tree. as you come back up you could just 'pop' them out of the array one by one. If the user presses the back button, you can cross check at the point of an action being made or pass the current URL to the server on a timed JavaScript AJAX call maybe which helps keep the array up to date.